# An Olympiad geometry question on area lemma.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, alternative-proof

In ABC, E, F, G are points on AB, BC, CA respectively such that $\frac{AE}{EB} = \frac{BF}{FC} = \frac{CG}{GA} = \frac{1}{3}$. K, L, M are the intersection points of the lines AF and CE, BG and AF, CE and BG, respectively. Suppose the area of ABC is 1; find the area of KLM.

I know there is a general formula when dividing in m:n ie. $\frac{(m-n)^2}{m^2+mn+n^2}$

P.S. please no Bary/ Complex

To verify the result, I put $m=n$ and it worked. Also, I tried the area lemma, Ceva's theorem but to no use. I tried this problem for a long time and then realised that Menelaus worked but as this excercise was in the area and ratio section, that felt like 'cheating' as I want to know the author's intended method.

Thanks!

Comment: A useful general lemma: if lines $PQ$ and $RS$ intersect at a point $X$, then $PX : QX = \frac{[PRS]}{[QRS]}$. You can solve the problem with just this lemma and ratios of areas of triangles with the same angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Let [.] denote areas. Evaluate the area ratio

$$\frac{[CBM]}{[EBM]}= \frac{[CBG]}{[EBG]}
= \frac{\frac 14 [ABC]}{\frac 34 [ABG]}= \frac{\frac 14 [ABC]}{\frac 34 \frac 34[ABC]}
=\frac 49 $$

which leads to the area $[CBM]$, and likewise $[ACK]$, $[BAL]$

$$[CBM] = \frac{4}{4+9} [CEB] = \frac{4}{13}\frac 34[ABC]
=\frac{3}{13} = [ACK] = [BAL] $$
Then
$$[KLM] = [ABC] -[CBM]- [ACK]-[BAL] =1-3\cdot\frac{3}{13}=\frac 4{13}$$

---

The derivation applies to general ratio $m:n$ as well
$$\frac{[CBM]}{[EBM]}=\frac{m(m+n)}{n^2}\implies 
\frac{[CBM]}{[CBE]}=\frac{m(m+n)}{m(m+n)+n^2} $$
$$\implies [CBM]= \frac{m(m+n)}{m(m+n)+n^2}\cdot\frac{n}{m+n}
=\frac{m n}{m^2+mn +n^2}$$
$$[KLM] = 1-3[CBM]= \frac{(m-n)^2}{m^2+mn +n^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer!

Answer (score 3):

The general case of this problem is called [Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%27s_theorem).  It states that if $EB/AE = x$, $FC/BF = y$, $GA/CG = z$, then $$\frac{[KLM]}{[ABC]} = \frac{(xyz-1)^2}{(xy+y+1)(yz+z+1)(zx+x+1)}.$$  Note I have taken the reciprocals so that in your case, $x = y = z = 3$.  The proof of this theorem is given in the Wikipedia link.

Comment: thanks, we can derive Routh's theorem without Menelaus theorem too right, in the way the above answer has depicted?